# Formatting standard function names in plot legends

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, traditional-form

Consider the following:

```
Quit[]
Format[Exp[x_], TraditionalForm]   (* e^{x_} *)
Format[Log[x_], TraditionalForm]   (* log(x_) *)
```

Now `Plot[{Log[x], Exp[x]}, {x,1,2}, PlotLegends->"Expressions"]` yields
[image]

So perhaps `PlotLegends` doesn't use the `TraditionalForm` output, since the formatting for `Exp` doesn't correspond. But now:

```
Unprotect[Log]
Format[Log[x_], TraditionalForm] := ln[x]
Protect[Log]

Format[Log[x_], TraditionalForm]    (* ln(x_) *)
```

and now issuing the same plot command yields
[image]

I would like `exp(x)` to print as `e^x`, so:

```
Unprotect[Exp]
Format[Exp[x_], TraditionalForm] := e^x
```

and I get `SetDelayed: Tag Power in MakeBoxes[e^{x_}, TraditionalForm] is Protected`. (Note: I've tried this both with the Mathematica `ESC e e ESC` and just the character `e`, with the same results.

So I guess I have two questions:

1. What format is used for PlotLegends?
2. Why is there a difference in behavior between `Log` and `Exp` in the above code?

Comment: Would using `PlotLegends -> {Format[Exp[x], TraditionalForm], Format[Log[x], TraditionalForm]}` not solve your issue?

Comment: Or perhaps `Plot[{Log[x],Exp[x]},{x,1,2},PlotLegends->"Expressions"]/.HoldForm:> TraditionalForm`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For question 1, `PlotLegends` uses `TraditionalForm`, but it wraps the functions in `HoldForm`. For question 2, look at the `FullForm` of `Exp[x]`:

```
FullForm[Exp[x]]
```

> Power[E,x]

The `Exp[x]` in the `Format` statement evaluates, which is why you get a `SetDelayed::write` message:

```
Unprotect[Exp]
Format[Exp[x_], TraditionalForm] := E^x
Protect[Exp]
```

> {Exp}
>
> -SetDelayed::write: Tag Power in MakeBoxes[E^x_,TraditionalForm] is Protected.
>
> $Failed
>
> {Exp}

So, you need to prevent evaluation by using `HoldPattern`:

```
Unprotect[Exp]
Format[HoldPattern@Exp[x_], TraditionalForm] := E^x
Protect[Exp]
```

> {Exp}
>
> {Exp}

Now, let's see if it worked:

```
Hold[Exp[x]]//TraditionalForm
```

> Hold[E^x]

Note that the above is one of the reasons (evaluation leaks) I prefer using `MakeBoxes` rules instead, something along the lines of:

```
Unprotect[Exp]
Exp /: MakeBoxes[Exp[x_], TraditionalForm] := MakeBoxes[Power[E,x], TraditionalForm]
Protect[Exp]
```

> {Exp}
>
> {Exp}

Comment: One question, though: why does my original construct work for `Log` and not for `Exp`? Is it because `Log` appears to be built-in (`FullForm[Log[x]]` is `Log[x]`) while `Exp` is just shorthand for an invocation of the `Power` function?